# How to convert JavaScript regex to c# regex

Tags: javascript, c#

How to convert the below Java Script to C#.

function test() {

```
var patKeyValue = /"(.*)"\s*=\s*"(.*)"/; // "key" = "value";            
var patCommentSingle = /\/\/(.*)/; // single line comment
var patCommentBlock = /\/\*(.*)\*\//; /* block comment on one line */
var patCommentStart = /\/\*(.*)/; /* block comment start */
var patCommentEnd = /(.*)\*\//;  /* block comment end */
```

}

Comment: Can you post your C# code please to show us where you have the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex itself is an standard. So this regex should work equally on C# too. But what you have to do is escaping this expression. Do it by hand or let it do by websites like https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

Answer (score 2):

Replace the opening and closing / with ", and escape any enclosed " or \ between the opening and closing /, using the back-slash \ escape character. So the first example becomes:

```
var patKeyValue = "\"(.*)\"\\s*=\\s*\"(.*)\""; // "key" = "value";
```